# Is it possible to get system configuration value in Static block/ CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block, cms-pages, magento2.2.2

I have eight static block list. Client want to change some part of string in these static block according the current month. I can achieve this though the code, but client have access only of backend, so is there any way to change the content in all static block from the single place without editing the code?

Comment: Hello @Dsingh is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find Below answer help to you.

Goto System->Custom Variables
then Create New Variable like this https://prnt.sc/hnv598
then Goto CMS Block write {{customVar code=Test}} or insert variables.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, @moin-malek this is helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, your client want to add dynamic date somewhere in static block. It is not possible out of the box, you should create some kind of reusable widget which your client might use to achieve his goals and which will wrap your logic in reusable element.

Edit:
It is not mentioned in description but in the title that you want to get system config value in block; if that is really the case then you can do:

```
{{config path="system/config/path"}}
```

For example: `{{config path="general/store_information/country_id"}}`

Comment: It is not working, i have added this in the block : <p>{{config path="free-catalogue/general/month"}}</p>

Answer (score 0):

> **Yes it's possible to use store configuration value in static block**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Config\Structure\AvailableVariables">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configPaths" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sectionName/groupName" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sectionName/groupName/fieldName" xsi:type="string">AddDefaultValue</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Now you can use this value in any static block in admin**

```
{{config path='sectionName/groupName/fieldName'}}
```